# PHP Script that creates folder and populates with specific files

Tags: php, file-io, directory

using a tool (PHPRunner) that allows me to run a PHP script right after we enter data into the db.

*Facing a challenge at the moment which is:*
once the data is submited in a form, want it to create a folder (the name of the folder comes from data entered in that form in a column that's entered);

From my research, this can be handled with `mkdir()`.

There's actually a good script for that, shared already in this community previously:

```
if(!file_exists(dirname($file)))
    mkdir(dirname($file), 0777, true);
//do stuff with $file.
```

**My question is:**
inside of that folder, want it to create files *AND* populate those files with data that comes from multiple tables.

*Never done something like that...*

**Any suggestions/thoughts in how to do it?**

I know it might take a few days to implement it, no worries on that.

Comment: `file_put_contents()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: @Kisaragi Don't forget [`touch()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php)